# failed unmarshalling build config deploy.yaml:

Tags: maven, yaml, google-cloud-build

After running the cloud build trigger: It shows

> Failed to trigger build: failed unmarshalling build config deploy.yaml: unknown field "images" in cloudbuild_go_proto.BuildStep

I used below YAML file:

```
Steps:
# Build the latest version.
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args:
  - 'build'
  - '--tag=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/mvn'
  - '.'
# Minimally invoke Maven.
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/mvn'
  args: ['--version']

# Run example builds.
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/mvn'
  args: ['install']
  dir: 'xxx/xx'

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn"
  args: 
    [
      'appengine:update',
      '-Dappengine.appId=xxx',
      '-Dappengine.version=xxx',
      '-Dbookshelf.bucket=xxx'
    ]

- images: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/mvn'
```

Error: Failed to trigger build: failed unmarshalling build config deploy.yaml: unknown field "images" in cloudbuild_go_proto.BuildStep

Answer (score 3):

The structure is wrong. You have to start with `steps` and then `images`. Here a working example from one of my project:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/bq-to-ftp', '.' , '-f', 'Dockerfile']
  # push the container image to Container Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/bq-to-ftp']
images:
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/bq-to-ftp'
```